# add_filter( 'single_template' ... not working although used correctly?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, filter, wpmu

I'm on WPMU (if that matters) but as far as I know plugins should be working properly...the usual rules should apply.

I've attempted to use the filter `add_filter( 'single_template', 'ss_get_stock_image_template' );` but its not being called. Is there anything being done wrong here?

```
function ss_get_stock_image_template($single_template) {
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type == 'image') {
        $single_template = ss_img_lib. 'single-image.php';      

    }
    return $single_template;
}

add_filter( 'single_template', 'ss_get_stock_image_template' );
```

Answer (score 0):

To my amazing surprise, changing the `menu_position` in my custom post type declaration fixed it... wow...